# AngularJS doesn't apply changes, using $apply ends with error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and have a problem with my first project:
If I update a special $scope-variable the changes aren't applied. Changing another $scope-variable works fine. I tried to use $scope.$apply but it says "$apply already in progress". With ng-inspector (a Chrome extension) I found out that the new value is assigned to the $scope-variable but this change isn't applied by ng-repeat...
Here's the code (coffeescript). The problematic variable is named "ingreds":

```
angular.module 'magicPeda', ['ngDragDrop']
.controller 'IngredientsCtrl', ($scope, $http) ->
  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  base = null
  $http.get('/base').then (iResponse) ->
     base = iResponse.data
     $scope.ingreds = base
     $scope.combination = []
  $scope.cook = ->
    ids = []
    for ingreds in ($scope.combination)
      ids.push ingreds._id
    ids = JSON.stringify ids
    IdString = $.param({ingredids: ids})
    request = $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/cook",
      data: IdString,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then (response) ->
      base.push response.data
      $scope.ingreds = base
      $scope.combination = []
  $scope.reset = ->
    $scope.ingreds = base
    $scope.combination = []
```

and the html part:

```
  <div class="container" ng-controller="IngredientsCtrl">
    <table class="table" >
      <tr ng-repeat="ingredient in ingreds">
        <td>
          <img ng-src="/images/{{ingredient.pic}}" data-drag="true" ng-model="ingredient"
          -jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}"  ng-hide="!ingredient.name"></img>
          {{ingredient.name}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" ng-model="combination" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}" style='height:150px; bottom: 0px;'>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="height: 100%" ng-click="reset()" ng-show="combination[0].name">Reset</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="item in combination track by $index">
          <img ng-show="item.name" data-drag="false" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone'}" ng-model="combination" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}}, placeholder: 'keep'}" ng-src="/images/{{item.pic}}" />
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="height: 100%" ng-click="cook()">Cook!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you could try using $timeout(function () { }); instead

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you posted the javascript rather than the coffee script. But I think the problem is that you appear to be updating the scope variable through a base local variable. If you update your scope.ingreds variable directly when your deferred promise resolves then angular should see that as part of its digest cycle and update the view as required.